# Including images in Angular 17+ library using Nx framework

Tags: angular, signals, ngrx, nrwl-nx, angular-standalone-components

I recently started using standalone components in Angular 17+. I am loving the new features and using @ngrx/signals. However, am not sure how to include assets (images) in my component as it is a standalone component in the libs folder. Can anyone assist

I have searched the web but have not found anyone with a similar problem or solution to this problem.

Comment: can you specify your problem

Comment: I am using Nx to create a standalone Angular library. I want to know how to include images in this component but it is not connecting to my assets in the app.